# How to insert a countif column on each row of the table?

Tags: jquery, mysql, sql, excel, countif

Basically I have a table with lots of rows, this column is called "source_id" and "time spent", in the column "source_id" I have repeated items that I will need to analyse their "time spent" them later on excel. On this step I will need to identify all the repeated "source_id"`s that appear on this column.

On excel, I was doing something like

```
=countif(The entire source_id column, A2)
```

Repeated for all items below and I'd filter later all values greater than 1 meaning that they are duplicates.

I'd need to make something similar through SQL because when I do that on excel my file crashes. (I believe when I export to excel this wont go crash because I will have fewer items being analysed separately)

OR

I was thinking about to merge in a single row all the one's who have the same "source_Id" but I'd still need to have the "time spent" value that they had previously.

It would be something like:
Source_ID - Time Spent1 - Time Spent2

Please find attached image from the output
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLhQL.png)

Any thoughts?

Comment: Provide some sample data with your expected output.

Comment: Your question is very difficult to understand.  As @mkRabbani suggests, data and output would be helpful.  I am guessing a CASE statement may do what you want, but don't have enough information to say.

Comment: output example done

Comment: hey any help in here?

Comment: hey any help on this?